# Simple Typescript es5 library

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I am really confused about how to create a simple es5 library that is not loaded as a module but rather like an old-fashioned iife.

All I am trying to do is to create a single file that will be included in the html

```html
<script src="foo.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

and then be able to instantiate the function

```js
var f = new Foo();
```

I am using webpack to bundle the assets.

Do I need babel to polyfill to an iife or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the library injects the class into the browser's global variable. May be you shoud add this in your lib code.

```js
class Foo {

}
window.Foo = Foo
```

For example: [This is how jquery does it.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/exports/global.js)

Comment: The point is that the client should call and initialize the class, not the library it self.

Comment: Usually the library injects the class into the browser's global variable.

Comment: For example: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/exports/global.js 
 `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery`

Comment: thank you, that's what I was missing I guess. If you would like you could edit your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: sure, I have edited the answer